# Adding input and output parameter to a DatabricksStep - Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: python, azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service

We are using AMLS for creating and registering a pipeline which runs on a pre-defined Databricks cluster.
In the AMLS workspace, there is our Databricks notebook which should be executed in the DatabricksStep.

We want to save a file into a Blob-storage container. Therefore, we have added the parameters "outputs" and "notebook_params" to the DatabricksStep:
It is important that we use the DatabricksStep, but irrelevant whether the Notebook (Python script basic_DatabricksStep_script.py) is in AMLS or the Databricks workspace.

How we try to save a file into the Blob storage container:

Here is the Python script, which should be executed in the DatabricksStep

```
%%writefile $source_directory/basic_DatabricksStep_script.py

dbutils.widgets.get("input")
i = getArgument("input")
print ("Param -\'input':")
print (i)

dbutils.widgets.get("output")
dbutils.widgets.get("output")
o = getArgument("output")
print ("Param -\'output':")
print (o)
data = [('value1', 'value2')]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data)

z = o + "/output.txt"
df2.write.csv(z)
```

This is how we define the DatabricksStep

```
def_blob_store = Datastore(ws, "input_datastore")
step_1_input = DataReference(datastore=def_blob_store, path_on_datastore="dbtest",
data_reference_name="input")

output_data_folder_name = "output"
output_data_folder = PipelineData(output_data_folder_name, Datastore.get(ws, "output_datastore"))

dbNbWithExistingClusterStep = DatabricksStep(
name="DBFSReferenceWithExisting",
run_name='DBFS_Reference_With_Existing',
source_directory = source_directory,
python_script_name = "basic_DatabricksStep_script.py",
inputs=[step_1_input],
outputs=[output_data_folder],
compute_target=databricks_compute,
existing_cluster_id="XXXXXX",
allow_reuse=True,
permit_cluster_restart=True
)
```

Here is a picture for making it clearer what we want to achieve:
[image]

Currently, our pipeline is not getting built by AMLS even though we followed the examples of the official GitHub notebook for learning about the DatabricksStep class.
Can you make our pipeline work, please?

Thank you in advance for your support!

Answer (score 0):

We can get the path through the **API tokens**.

- Goto Azure Databricks User interface
- Goto "**User Settings**" option
- Click on "**Generate New Token**"
- You can see Databrick file explorer and "**right click**", choose "**Copy filepath**".

Comment: sorry, I do not understand how this might help to solve the issue. Can you please clarify what you mean? Maybe you should reread the question again.

Comment: The question is edited and changed. Initially when it posted, it is speaking about getting output folder path. My answer is regarding it, now it was edited by the owner. So, my answer looks irrelevant.